# Empty $_FILE and $_POST superglobals when uploading via File transfer

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova, file-transfer

I'm creating a mobile web app where user will be able to upload its picture and use it as an avatar. Testing it in android studio emulator everything works fine and the successful function alerts that everything is done. However my $_POST and $_FILES are empty.

JS:

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function clearCache() {
    navigator.camera.cleanup();
}

var retries = 0;
function onCapturePhoto(fileURI) {
    var win = function (r) {
        clearCache();
        retries = 0;
        alert('Done!');
    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        if (retries == 0) {
            retries ++
            setTimeout(function() {
                onCapturePhoto(fileURI)
            }, 1000)
        } else {
            retries = 0;
            clearCache();
            alert('Ups. Something wrong happens!');
        }
        alert(error);
    }

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

    var params = {};
    params.username = curr_username;
    alert('username: ' + params.username);

    options.params = params;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("some-server/file_upload.php"), win, fail, options, true);
}

function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, onFail, {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
    });
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_user_pw","db_name") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    // ako u javasdcriptu nemaš pristup user_id-u, treba poslat username i ovdje fetchat iz baze odgovarajući user_id
    $output = print_r($_POST, true);
    file_put_contents('username.txt', $output);
    $output = print_r($_FILES, true);
    file_put_contents('file.txt', $output);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $tmp_file_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $file_name = "images/" . $username . '.jpg';

    // remove the file if exists
    if(file_exists($file_name)) {
        unlink($file_name); 
    }
    // upload new file
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file_name, $file_name);



    $file_name = "path_to_images_folder/".$file_name;

    // update database
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET avatar = '$file_name' WHERE id = (SELECT id WHERE username = '$username')");

    if($q)
        echo "success";
    else
        echo "error";

?>
```

Any ideas why this is happening since i'm loosing my mind